# Multiple Search Terms and Output Files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file I'm searching through and printing the results to a file. I'm wondering if it's possible to amend the code below to read in multiple search terms i.e. print any line that has "test" or "hello" (user will specify) in it but have Python create a new output file for each search term?

i.e. Ofile1 would hold all lines containing "test"
Ofile2 would hold all lines containing "hello" and so on

```
f = open('file3.txt') #input file

term = raw_input("What would you like to search for?") #takes an input to be searched

for line in f:
    if term in line:
        print (line) #print line of matched term

f.close() #close file
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Have you been looking for some information before you ask? It's very simple issue.

Comment: Don't mean to sound disrespectful but I wouldn't ask if I had found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based of @new user code (improved some error) you could do something like this:

```
terms = raw_input("What would you like to search for?")
terms = terms.split(" ")
for term in terms:
    f = open('text.txt')
    filename = '{}_output.txt'.format(term)
    o = open(filename, 'w')
    for line in f:
        if term in line:
            o.write(line)
    o.close()
    f.close()
```

Maybe you can think that is better open the file once and check some term per each line. Depending of number of terms it will be more or less efficient, if you want could research about it using really big files to check execution times and learn a bit more.

Comment: Thank you very much. Out of interest why does it not find anything when searching for ".jpg" but will find all the "jpg" files? Amended code to ignore the case

Answer (score 0):

Split your term by spaces. then use a for loop to loop through all of the terms.

ex:

```
terms = term.split(" ")
for t in terms:
    filename = t +"_output.txt"
    o = open(filename,'w')
    for line in f:
        if t in line:
            o.write(line) #print line of matched term
    o.close()
```

Comment: This example code fails because the name of `t` is used like `term` after. And if the user input is more of one words the code only save the file of first, the second (and so on)  not because the pointer inside of file is in the last file and you dont move to begining of file when you check second (and so on) word. You can use [tell method](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) at the end of you code to check this.
And also you need close all files that you open.
This is only an advice, we are here to learn.